# Cannot get the Selenium Firefox Driver to work with Java

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

I have tried different versions of both Firefox, the Selenium server and the FirefoxDriver, but can't get it to work. Whenever I call the following code:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
URL = "https://www.google.com/"; 
driver.get(URL);
```

, the browser opens but doesn't go to the url and I get an exception, stating:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:    com.google.common.base.Joiner$MapJoiner.appendTo(Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
at com.google.common.net.MediaType.toString(MediaType.java:714)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpCommandCodec.encode(JsonHttpCommandCodec.java:197)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:130)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.execute(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:165)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:362)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:572)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
at com.kaisle.intdes.Main.util.SeleniumTest.main(SeleniumTest.java:16)
```

My current configuration is:

Selenium-firefox-driver 2.45.0

Selenium-remote-driver 2.45.0

Selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0

Firefox 27

I also tried with 2.39.0, 2.43.1 and other versions of Firefox but none of those worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced same issue. I feel that it is something to do with the jars you have associated to the project.

For webdriver, just include this jar - `Selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0`. if you had included anything else, you can remove it **OR** In the eclipse, move the order of this jar `Selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0` first (`Order and Export` tab), If you need anything else like `Selendriod` for android, should come next.

Comment: Thanks, downloading the server-jar and moving it to the build path instead of including it through Maven, actually made it work.